# Linux 64b dangerous kernel exploit

Tags: linux, kernel, exploit

Many of you know the recent and dangerous kernel exploit CVE-2010-3081.

See **[/.](http://linux.slashdot.org/story/10/09/20/0217204/Linux-Kernel-Exploit-Busily-Rooting-64-Bit-Machines)**

What is the actual risk for a server?
Do we have to patch urgently all systems?

Or, since it seems only a local user may gain *root* access, standalone servers are pretty safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like it's only locally exploitable, but that actually means "exploitable by locally running code" - if you let people upload and run CGIs on your system, you're screwed anyway.

If no code can get on your system from the outside, you're ok. Example: database server that only exposes the MySQL TCP socket *should* be safe (that's IMHO, you have to do your homework).

Personally I don't run any 32bit code on x86_64 servers, so I actually never had compatiblity compiled in any of my kernels, just like I do for any feature I'm not actively using (yes I do roll my own kernels for prod systems).